# Interpreting statistical formulas using python (mu + sigma * data)

Tags: python, bigdata, statistics, visualization, descriptive-statistics

I am working with data using python. I tried to plot a histogram using `mathplotlib`.

I found a few examples on how to analyze data to get more accurate graphs.

So I coded:

```
# Call csvfile
csvdata = pandas.read_csv('data/education_data/' + filename + '.csv', low_memory=False, encoding='latin-1')

# Convert amount field into int()
def str_to_int(mainList):
    for item in mainList:
        newList = [(int(item.replace('$', '').replace(',', '')) / (1000000)) for item in mainList]
    return newList

# Convert str to int using str_to_int() function
csvdata['str_costo'] = str_to_int(csvdata['Cuantía'])
sigma = numpy.std(csvdata['str_costo'])
mean = numpy.mean(csvdata['str_costo'])
x = mean + sigma * csvdata['str_costo']
```

But, I saw one step in particular:

```
In[0] x = mean + sigma * csvdata['str_costo']
Out[0] 1.371822e+08, 1.608953e+08, etc...
```

All values from `csvdata['str_costo']` are integers.

My question is how to interpret `x` values.

Theoretically what they mean?

Comment: It looks like some vague attempt at constructing (upper) confidence intervals.

Comment: It would help if you could share the source of the code.

Comment: @Shagun I added the code. Actually, the data comes from csvfile. So I used numpy to get `std` and `mean`, and I added `x` when I saw a matplotlib example. I would like to know how to interpret `x` value.